# Assigning an array to a derived object

Tags: c++, class, derived

I am trying to write a Matrix Class for a projects. I seperated the square matrix as a derived class. But when I try to perform the minor operation for the determinant, I can't assign the matrix members to the my derived class objects. How can I perform these operation? Actually, I tried a lot, I couldn't make a success. Here is the code;

```
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const Matrix &);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &, const Matrix &);
private:
    int num_col;
    int num_row;
    int **mits;
public:
    Matrix(const int=0 ,const int=0);
    Matrix (const Matrix &right);
    ~Matrix();
    int          DisplayMenu();
    void         gotoxy(int         x,  int y);
    int          getRow();
    int          getCol();
    int**        getMatrix();
    virtual void print();
    Matrix       operator+(const   Matrix&);
    Matrix       operator-(const   Matrix&);
    Matrix       operator*(const   Matrix&);
    Matrix       transMatrix(const Matrix&);
    Matrix       &operator=(const  Matrix&);
};

#endif
#   include <iostream>
#   include "Matrix.h"
#include <windows.h>
#   include <string>
using namespace std;
class SquareMatrix :public Matrix
{
    int **sMits;
public:
    SquareMatrix(const int=0 ,const int=0);
    ~SquareMatrix();
    virtual void print();
    SquareMatrix minor( const int,const int,const int);
    int deter( SquareMatrix &mat);
    /*SquareMatrix operator*(const SquareMatrix &);
    virtual void print(const Matrix &);*/
};

SquareMatrix::SquareMatrix(const int row ,const int col)
    :Matrix(row,col)
{
}

SquareMatrix::~SquareMatrix()
{
}

int SquareMatrix::deter(SquareMatrix &a)
{
    SquareMatrix M;
    int d = 0;       // value of the determinant
    int rows =a.getRow();
    int cols =a.getCol();
    sMits=a.getMatrix();
    // this is a square matrix
    if (rows == 1)
    {
        // this is a 1 x 1 matrix
        d = sMits[0][0];
    }
    else if (rows == 2)
    {
        // this is a 2 x 2 matrix
        // the determinant of [a11,a12;a21,a22] is det = a11*a22-a21*a12
        d = sMits[0][0]* sMits[1][1] - sMits[1][0]* sMits[0][1];
    }
    else
    {
        rows--;
        cols--;
        for (int c = 0; c <= cols; c++)
        {
            M= minor(c,rows,cols);
            d += (c%2 + c%2 - 1) * sMits[0][c] * deter(M);
        }
    }
    return d;
}

SquareMatrix SquareMatrix::minor(const int col,const int rows,const int cols)
{
//int rows =Matrix::getRow();
//int cols =Matrix::getCol();
    int **Mits=Matrix::getMatrix();
    SquareMatrix min(rows , cols);
    cout<<min<<endl;
    for (int r = 1; r <= rows ; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c <= cols ; c++)
        {
            if (c!=(col))
            {
                if (c<col)
                {
                    min.sMits[r-1][c] = Mits[r][c];
                }
                else if (c>col)
                {
                    min.sMits[r-1][c-1] = Mits[r][c];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}

void SquareMatrix::print()
{
    Matrix::print();
}
```

Comment: Rule number 1. Make your code look good

Comment: Please include a minimal sample of what, exactly, isn't working for you.

Comment: in minor method, `int **Mits=Matrix::getMatrix();` does not make sense to me. `getMatrix()` is not static, so what do you expect to retrieve ?

Comment: This assignment `min.sMits[r-1][c-1] = Mits[r][c];` doesn't work. I want to assign each part of minor of the beginning matrix to the another proper derived object matrix. This is why I am using min.sMits. But I think I am using by mistaken. I know the masters is here. By the way, Thank you Shahbaz for your warning, from now on I will be more careful.

Comment: the meta-function `deter` seems to be both literate and statically evaluated :)

Comment: can you getting compile time errors? If any errors can you put those to with your question?

Comment: I don't get any errors. At the point that the assignment would occur, the program tries to close itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of problems with this code, but I think the particular problem is that **min** is a **SquareMatrix**, and the **SquareMatrix** constructor calls the **Matrix** constructor, which presumably initialises **Matrix::mits**, but I don't see **SquareMatrix::sMits** being initialised by anything.

Anyway, this line

```
min.sMits[r-1][c] = Mits[r][c];
```

accesses **SquareMatrix::sMits** in **min**, but **SquareMatrix::sMits** is uninitialised, which would cause a segfault/bad access exception. You probably meant to access **Matrix::mits**, but are unable to because **Matrix::mits** is *private*, and **SquareMatrix** only inherits *public* **Matrix**.

If you want to access **SquareMatrix::sMits** in **min**, you need to populate **sMits** somehow, or give protected access to mits, and use that instead. i.e.

```
class Matrix
{
 protected:
     int** mits;
```

and then

```
min.mits[r-1][c] = Mits[r][c];
```

Comment: I know the protected mits works. But I don't want to use this. Isn't it enough to initialize like `sMits=a.getMatrix(); ` for sMits. Actually, I would be very glad If you point out the other problems in my code.

Comment: I assume you mean min.sMits = min.getMatrix() ? The SquareMatrix::minor function has no object 'a'.

Comment: I assume you mean min.sMits = min.getMatrix()?The SquareMatrix::minor function has no object 'a'.Yes, you can do that, but it's very ugly coding and breaks encapsulation. Other problems in the SquareMatrix::minor function is that you don't do any bounds checking on rows or cols to ensure they are <= num_col or num_row. Your else if (c>col) is redundant as you have already checked it is not equal, should be just else. When you return min, it is returned by copy, so the whole object will be copied on return. If col == -1 [c-1] will be out of bounds. Do you need code?